XUnit не отображает MemberData тесты с моим классом
Пишу XUnit тест сервиса. Один тест - одна особенность. При этом использую [Theory].
Если тесты проверяют базовые классы, всё хорошо, никаких проблем. Тесты дробятся в обозревателе и можно работать с каждым отдельно.
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(Data))]
public void Test(DateTime entity)
{
    // Assert
}

Если параметром выступает мой класс, тесты выглядят как один, а о наличии нескольких итераций можно узнать лишь по выводу результатов.
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(Data))]
public void Test(MyClass entity)
{
    // Assert
}


Испробовал [MemberData(nameof(Data))] [InlineData(Data)]
Слишком громоздко показалось использовать [ClassData(typeof(DataClassName))]
